# Does Ractive recognize NODE_ENV for its debugging?

Tags: node.js, ractivejs

I'm using Ractive v0.7.x and I've noticed in chrome console that they suggest to set `Ractive.DEBUG = false` when deploying in production.

I started going this way:

`Ractive.DEBUG = document.location.hostname.match(/^appdev\./);`

Still, I'm using webpack and I discovered that React dev uses `NODE_ENV` variable (like express) to know whether its debug parts should be stripped of the production compiled.

They suggest in Webpack conf to use something like

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {NODE_ENV: '"production"'}
})
```

Now, my question is if Ractive recognizes this env variable? it would be very useful for all of us that packs the code with webpack or other 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Ractive doesn't use `NODE_ENV`. You need to set `Ractive.DEBUG`. I personally use the same approach as you - setting the value based on the hostname.